# UIView truncate instead of stretching

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

I have two small `UIViews` on top of each other, they have exactly same frame size. I'm trying to change the width of the top `UIView` so that i can see the bottom `UIView` AND at the same time I would like my top view to truncate from right instead of stretching... How can i go about doing this?

I'm using Storyboard for creating views etc however, i'm changing the width of the top `UIView` programmatically...

```
self.bottomView.frame = CGRectMake(175, 60, 95,20);
self.topView.frame = CGRectMake(175, 60, 74, 20);
```

I have set the stretching to '0' in the Attributes inspector but it didnt work.
How do i make the top `UIView` truncate from right instead of stretching?

**Example:** I have 1 & 5 dollar bill on top of each other, $1 is on top and $5 is in the bottom, so if i decrease the $1 bill width to half, it should show me half $1 bill on left and half $5 bill on right... 
what is happening now is that when i decrease the width of 1$ to half, i see FULL $1 bill STRETCHED on the left and half $5 bill..

Comment: I'll be happy to provide more details if you could point out what you need.. i don't even have code to post since i'm using storyboard to create both the UIViews...

Comment: I am wondering what you mean by "to truncate from right instead of stretching". are you trying to do an animation or is it the way you want it to be presented? do your topView/BottomView have images or are these plain uiviews?

Comment: I have given an example in my question, hope that helps... i'm not doing any animation in this. yes, i do have images on these views.

Comment: @Ahmad here you set same x and y coordinate to both view and same height ,BUT here width is differ see bottomView's width is 95 and topview's width is 74.. just do some changes there and let me know.. :)

Comment: @ParasJoshi i changed the width on purpose. I decreased the width so that i can see the right side of bottom view.

Comment: No, the problem is not solved yet.

Comment: would you show me any screen shots

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `contentMode` property of the top view to something like `UIViewContentModeLeft`. More specifically, avoid any of the content modes that contain "Fill" in their name, as they'll cause the view to scale its content to fit the view.

Comment: @OP: The default value of the contentMode property is UIViewContentModeScaleToFill . That is why you are seeing it stretched.

Answer (score 2):

May be it is because of `autoresizingMask`.
Set bottom `UIView` `autoresizingMask` to flexible width as I have shown here.

Green one is top `UIView`(z-index < z-index of red one) and red one is bottom `UIView`.

[image]